# White space when Actionbar is hidden in OS versions higher than 6.0?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I created a new android project in Android 6.0. In activity, I do `getSupportActionbar().hide()` (in `OnCreate()`). Actionbar was hidden, but white space is showing? Please help me this problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is **best & easy** way to hide default action bar from android activity.

Put these two styles in `res>values>styles.xml`. You may already have `AppTheme`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in your manifest class

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Then it could be your layout problem, can you post your `layout.xml`

Comment: I think it not layout problem.I just create project in android 6.0..this layout default android studio.

Comment: You still need to post xml and java code. Because that's all you have to inspect.

Comment: Where is it dude?

Comment: remove `getSupportActionBar().hide();` use only my method

Comment: Can you post your output layout screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

package com.example.administrator.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

}